# VBScript for Uninstall not finding anything

Tags: windows-server-2003, vbscript

I started using a standard uninstall script, and it wasn't working, so I decided to see if it was even finding any progams at all, and it seems it isn't.  It works on Windows 7 but not on the other the Windows 2003 server I need to use it on.  I'm logged in as local Admnistrator,

The script below created the error:

```
Line: 4
Char: 1
Error: 0x80041010
Code: 80041010
Source: (null)
```

**Code:**

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Product")
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
    MsgBox("hi")
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code you see is "Invalid Class".  Server 2003 does not include the MSI Provider for WMI by default.

From [Operating System Availability of WMI Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392726(v=vs.85).aspx#windows_installer_provider):

> **Windows Server 2003:**   The Windows Installer provider—also known as the MSI provider—is included on the CD as an optional Windows component that you can install using **Control Panel**. Optional installation of the Windows Installer provider ensures backward compatibility with the Windows XP and Windows 2000 feature sets.

You'll need to install from

- "Add Remove Windows Components"

  - "Management and Monitoring Tools"

    - "WMI Windows Installer Provider"

[image]

Comment: Ok, I don't have the disk to install the component at the moment but that looks right.  Thanks.